# Win the relay competition by selecting the longer path for competitors

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Two teams relay race: members of a team of three take turns running from the point P to a points on the circle; A for the first, B for the second, and C for the third, starting and returning at point P, transferring the baton at point P.

The points A, B, and C are set by the organizers of the competition.

Assuming that all runners have the same rate, each team selects the point P for the other team. Your task to maximize the length of the run for the competitors, by selecting the best point P to improve your probability to beat the competition.

[image]

The basic mathematical problem can be described as follows:

> Given three points $A$, $B$, and $C$ and the circle that goes through them, find the point $P$ on the circle that maximizes $PA + PB + PC$.

Comment: I assume we can assume that C and A are diametrically opposite, as appears to be indicated?

Comment: If you want to, but actually the A, B, C, points are randomly chosen on the circle. No need for this assumption to solve the puzzle.

Comment: The direction is pre determined, from P to A and back, from P to B and back, and the last lag fro C to P and back.

Comment: Do you know of a nice solution to this?

Comment: I know a solution which is relatively simple if you know some calculus. It is solvable without the need to get in complex algebraic calculations, which the brute force approach, which may be solved this way but I never needed it. This is why I think the problem qualifies as a puzzle.

Comment: @Moti I tried the classic trick of using the physical interpretation that the sum of the unit forces pointing at P from A, B, and C must point radially, but this too gave an algebraic equation that wasn't too nice, as did the calculus. Is there something nicer that that?

Comment: if ABC form an equilateral triangle there are 3 answers - which one do we choose?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I suppose that comment was meant to be on my answer. To answer this: It doesn't matter which 2 you choose in that case. You will have 3 possible answers yes but all these three answr give walks that are same in length and are the best solution

Comment: @IvoBeckers; no, it wasn't

Comment: @JonMarkPerry aah ok, my bad

Comment: So basically we're trying to maximize $PA + PB + PC$ given $A$, $B$, and $C$?

Comment: Also, you can draw a circle that goes through three points in GeoGebra. No need for a center and radius.

Comment: @Joe, this is the proper interpretation - maximize the sum of the three segments. You could farther complicate the question by assuming three runners with different speeds, than it becomes some what more challenging - I need to work on that one and if successful, will let you know.

Comment: I also got a formula that wasn't really nice.

Comment: The whole story of the runners just confuses things as evidenced by the answers so far. I suggest removing the preamble and simply stating the geometrical problem as at the bottom of the question. Note: We need to know whether distance is measured in straight lines or around the circle.

Comment: This a puzzle not a math problem site - so it is presented as a puzzle. As I stated some other place - it has to be straight lines. Along the circle P is coinciding with B.

Comment: Given that the accepted answer uses nothing but standard algebra and calculus methods, with nothing really nice or clever, I think this is a math problem rather than a puzzle and should be closed as such.

Comment: There is a more elegant solution that I will present - that is the "puzzle" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that AC is larger than AB or BC. If P is on the arc AB, then we can construct P' where PP' is parallel to BC. Then P'B=PC, P'C=PB, and P'A>PA:
[image: 1]]
Similarly, if P is on arc BC, we can also find a better point. So to maximize PA+PB+PC, P must be on arc AC.

[image: 2]]
Let the diameter of the circle be 1. PA=$\sin(θ)$, PB=$\sin(θ+γ)$, and PC=$\sin(β-θ)$. We need to find the maximum of PA+PB+PC, which is either when the derivative is zero, or at the boundaries θ=0 or θ=β. The derivative at θ=0 is $1+\cos(γ)-\cos(β)$, which is positive. The derivative at θ=β is $\cos(β)-\cos(α)-1$, which is negative. Neither of these can be the maximum, so we set the derivative equal to zero:
$\cos(θ)+\cos(θ+γ)-\cos(β-θ)=0$

Using the sum and difference formulas,
 $\cos(θ)+\cos(θ)\cos(γ)-\sin(θ)\sin(γ)-\cos(θ)\cos(β)-\sin(θ)\sin(β)=0$

We can rearrange and factor to get
$\cos(θ)(1+\cos(γ)-\cos(β))=\sin(θ)(\sin(γ)+\sin(β))$

or equivalently:
$\tan(θ)=\frac{1+\cos(γ)-\cos(β)}{\sin(γ)+\sin(β)}$

Therefore P is maximized when $θ=\tan^{-1}(\frac{1+\cos(γ)-\cos(β)}{\sin(γ)+\sin(β)})$. I couldn't simplify this any further.

Comment: I wonder if differentiation will provide a solvable system for $\gamma$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @Moti I'm not sure what you mean. γ and β are fixed because they only depend on the locations of A, B, and C.

Comment: My error. Will get back to you after a careful review. Aren't you looking at arcs rather than straight lines?

Comment: @Moti Definitely straight lines. If I was using arcs then I would have PA=θ instead of sin(θ).

Comment: Should not $PA=2\sin\theta$?

Comment: Apart from this, your solution seems correct. There is somewhat simpler solution by selecting different angels. I will accept your answer, but please edit to reflect the proper trigonometry.

Comment: I chose the circle to have a diameter of 1. It would be 2sin(θ) if the radius was 1.

Comment: You need to check the function values at the endpoints, not the derivatives

Comment: @saulspatz sin(θ)+sin(θ+γ)-sin(β-θ) is a continuous function with a continuous derivative. If the derivative at 0 is positive, then increasing θ by a small amount increases the total distance, so the maximum cannot be at 0. Similarly, the maximum cannot be at β if the derivative there is negative.

Comment: Right, I didn't think it through.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer has the assumption that runners have to move along the circle. Although not clearly stated in the puzzle I think, although the image in the puzzle has straight lines**

I must say that this answer is mostly intuition so I am not sure it is proof enough and I even don't know if it is the correct answer but I have a good feeling it is.

WLOG assume A and B are the points that are closest together among the points ABC. Now take point A* and B* that are directly opposite of A and B on the circle. What you now notice is that if you pick P anywhere between A* and B* the walk from P to A plus the walk from P to B will be the same no matter where you pick it between these points, and notice that if you pick P outside these points the walk will become smaller. So you'll want to pick it between A* and B*. Now the third point C is left. Now we want the point that is farthest from C that is still between A* and B*. Logically this means that this point is either exactly on A* or on B*. So that is this is my answer:

From the two point that are closest together pick the opposite point on the circle that is farthest from the third point.

Comment: I don't think your statement that "if you pick P anywhere between A* and B* the walk from P to A plus the walk from P to B will be the same" is correct.

Comment: If A and B are 120° apart in a circle of radius 1, the distance from A* or B* is 3, but the distance from the point halfway between them is 2sqrt3.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. But let me explain it this way. If you are between A* and B*, then the shortest path to A is clockwise and to B counterclockwise or vice versa so the total distance is the greater arc between A and B always. If you're outside this range the shortest path will be both clockwise or both counterclockwise. Maybe you are thinking of straight lines?

Comment: Or maybe I guess I misunderstood. It doesn't really indicate they should follow the circle. My answer is only correct if they move along the circle

Comment: I assumed they move in straight lines.

Comment: yeah you're right then

Comment: To help, the move is not along the circle, it is in straight lines, as stated: start at P, to A and back to P, to B and back to P, to C and back to P.

Comment: If you try to solve the challenge where the runners move along the circle , than P falls on B.

Answer (score 0):

I have an okay answer, but I'm struggling with the proof, so I'll post it anyways to see if anyone has thoughts.

The ideal location for P to maximize distance is

> Diametrically opposite B

My thought process:

> We are given no hard information about where B is, but let's just say it's between A and C on the lower half of the circle. (This is with my assumption that A and C are opposite one another). I checked the simple cases first- if B is at the very bottom, the ideal P is at the top, and if B is at A or C, then the ideal P is at the other point. So it looks as if the best solution for any B is for P to be directly opposite it.

-

> Now, I was thinking about how to prove this geometrically, and I tried doing some stuff with Ptolemy's theorem or the fact that if P and B are opposite, then PCBA forms a rectangle, but I didn't really get anywhere. And then of course I'd want to generalize for any A,B,C... But calculus is so much less fun...

Comment: I tried this with [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?ggbLang=en) and it wasn't the best point for P (at least in my testing). I think it would work in some situations, but I also think he wants a general rule or formula for the puzzle, and _not_ what would be best in _this_ case.

Comment: @Luxx, you are right, no interest in specific cases